Can I use games-howell post hoc for specific pairwise comparisons?
I will provide more context:
My initial intent was conducting a one-way ANOVA and then follow up with planned comparisons (contrasts). Sadly, the homogeneity of variances assumption was violated, and because the sample size differences in my project are huge, I decided to go for Welch's ANOVA test.
From what I understand, as planned contrasts also assume homogeneity of variances, I can no longer go for that for my analysis - so I thought about using games-howell.
The problem is that I do not need all the pairwise comparisons, and I don't know if doing the test just for specific comparisons is a correct methodology (I also did not find a function that supports it in R).
One option I thought about was just running the games-howell multiple times, each time with different 2 groups, and correct the inflated alpha myself with a bonferonni correction. Is this approach acceptable? is there a better way?
I will really appreciate any help on the matter.
Thanks in advance!
